# List of possible English words with some letters missing

Tags: web-apps, educational, language

Are there any websites where I can find the list of possible English words from a word with some letters missing?

Example word : "O_"

From "O_" (two letter word starting with O), the following list of words could be found:

- ON
- OR
- OF

Comment: Would an offline solution be an option, like a command line to search within a file containing all words?

Comment: Yea that would be good too but i dont know grep commands and the file must contain every possible english word

Comment: Such files can perhaps be obtained from an open source spell checker. Regex commands for the patterns you mention should also be easy to learn. But it was just a thought. I see you've already gotten a good answer below.

Comment: Heh, I remember many many years ago I used some Macquarie dictionary program to do this. Probably still have the CD somewhere, but there's certainly better options now.

Answer (score 4):

You can typically find such feature in crossword or scrabble helpers. E.g. you can use [Wordsmyth Crossword Puzzle Helper](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?mode=csm):

- online
- free
- support patterns

[image]

Comment: Another one that I've used: http://www.crosswordsolver.org/

Answer (score 4):

Oh, ow: no ox?

On a Linux system, it's standard to have a text file containing a list of English words, for the use of applications such as spell checkers. (Some spell checkers have their own list in a format that they can search faster than plain text.) A typical location is `/usr/share/dict/words` or `/usr/share/misc/words` or `/usr/lib/dict/words` or some such. The file may be called something like `american-english` or `american-english-huge` instead of `words`.

You can search this file from the command line with the [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) command. The basic syntax is `grep PATTERN FILE` or `<FILE grep PATTERN` (the second one is more convenient to edit the command line when you want to run several similar commands). Use the option `-x` to indicate that the pattern you provide should match the whole line rather than a substring. In a pattern, you can use `.` to mean “any character”, or something like `[abcde]` to mean any of the characters inside the brackets, or `.*` to mean a sequence of letters of any length. You may need to put quotes around the pattern if it contains brackets or stars. See the `grep` manual or any reference on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for what you can use in the pattern.

```
</usr/share/dict/words grep -x o.
</usr/share/dict/words grep -x 'tes.*g'
</usr/share/dict/words grep -Ex '[aelmpx]{7}'
```

Instead of using grep, you can of course open the word list file in your favorite text editor, if it has decent searching capabilities.

If you're running Windows, a way to get standard Linux tools is to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). You can download word lists from [SCOWL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wordlist/files/SCOWL/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`Wolfram|alpha`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), which allows querying for word patterns, for example:


```
ER___T
```

returns:

```
Ernest
errant
erudit
```

It's also free!

However the `Wolfram|alpha` engine does not recognize word patterns that are small, such as `O_`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use My Word List Offline Dictionary for Android.

You can search for patterns using wildcards: * to replace zero or more letters, or ? for one letter.

It has more words than any other app in the market. Over 800,000 words and terms.

Links:

My Word List - Make Word Lists - Offline Dictionary app for Android.

Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: I am the developer.